# Aligning vertical bar columns and labels nicely

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams, pgfplotstable, bar-chart

I am trying to draw (in `pgfplots`) bar diagram similar to this: [image]

When I do like this:

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  [
  title    = Energy in MJ (million joules) to generate \$1,
  xbar, 
  y=-0.4cm,
  bar width=0.3cm,
  enlarge y limits={abs=0.45cm},
  y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
  axis x line       = none,
  tickwidth         = 0pt,
  enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
  enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
  y tick label style={align=center,yshift=0.0cm},
  nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},  
  symbolic y coords = {Bitcoin,Litecoin,Monero,Ethereum,Rare earth metals,Platinum group metals, Gold,Copper},
  ytick={Bitcoin, Litecoin, Monero, Ethereum, Rare earth metals, Platinum group metals, Gold, Copper},
  ]

  \addplot table[col sep=comma,header=false] {
  4,Copper
  5,Gold
  6,Platinum group metals
  9,Rare earth metals
  9,Ethereum
  11,Monero
  15,Litecoin
  19,Bitcoin
};

  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

it aligns bars and y bar labels nicely:

[image]

But when I tried to separate into two categories:

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  [
  title    = Energy in MJ (million joules) to generate \$1,
  xbar, 
  y=-0.4cm,
  bar width=0.3cm,
  enlarge y limits={abs=0.45cm},
  y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
  axis x line       = none,
  tickwidth         = 0pt,
  enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
  enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
  y tick label style={align=center,yshift=0.0cm},
  nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},  
  symbolic y coords = {Bitcoin,Litecoin,Monero,Ethereum,Rare earth metals,Platinum group metals, Gold,Copper},
  ytick={Bitcoin, Litecoin, Monero, Ethereum, Rare earth metals, Platinum group metals, Gold, Copper},
  ]

  \addplot table[col sep=comma,header=false] {
  9,Ethereum
  11,Monero
  15,Litecoin
  19,Bitcoin
};

  \addplot table[col sep=comma,header=false] {
  9,Rare earth metals
  6,Platinum group metals
  5,Gold
  4,Copper
};

  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

I am getting quite a mess:

[image]

Could you please help me here to fix it?

P.s. I tried some ideas from related questions and was very close to my solution, but my `pgfplots` code became messy and would like to get a neat solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just add a `bar shift`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  [
  title    = Energy in MJ (million joules) to generate \$1,
  xbar, 
  y=-0.4cm,
  bar width=0.3cm,
  enlarge y limits={abs=0.45cm},
  y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
  axis x line       = none,
  tickwidth         = 0pt,
  enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
  enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
  y tick label style={anchor=north east,yshift=0.1cm},
  nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},  
  symbolic y coords = {Bitcoin,Litecoin,Monero,Ethereum,Rare earth metals,Platinum group metals, Gold,Copper},
  ytick={Bitcoin, Litecoin, Monero, Ethereum, Rare earth metals, Platinum group metals, Gold, Copper},
  ]

  \addplot table[col sep=comma,header=false] {
  9,Ethereum
  11,Monero
  15,Litecoin
  19,Bitcoin
};

  \addplot[bar shift=-5pt,fill=red!20] table[col sep=comma,header=false] {
  9,Rare earth metals
  6,Platinum group metals
  5,Gold
  4,Copper
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]